# Difference between runas.exe and Start-Process -Credential

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am playing around with setting up some scripts on a vpn on a client's network. This client generally assigns an ActiveDirectory account on their network and use it to manage permissions (eg. to databases). Ok, that makes sense.

But here is something that confuses me:

```
start-process runas.exe "/user:CLIENTDOMAIN\George.Mauer /netonly W:\tools\LINQPad4\LINQPad.exe
```

queries for a password and runs just fine (and I can access the database)

**But**

```
Start-Process W:\tools\LINQPad4\LINQPad.exe -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

and entering `CLIENTDOMAIN\George.Mauer` and my password at the popup prompt always results in an error

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Are these not the same thing? What's the difference between `runas` and `-Credential`? And a secondary question - how do I `Start-Job` with my `CLIENTDOMAIN\George.Mauer` credential?

Comment: I suspect difference comes from /netonly switch - TBH I do not know a way to pass this to Start-Process cmdlet directly, but I would guess that answer to this question. Or, in the end - how to simulate /netonly when using Start-Job cmdlet.

Comment: @BartekB - are you saying that from the standpoint of Windows runas does the same thing as PsCredential and the only issue is a missing API? If so I might be asking the wrong question.

Comment: This is a total SWAG but what happens if you try `Start-Process ... -credential (Get-Credential).GetNetworkCredential()`.

Comment: @KeithHill it returns a `PsNetworkCredential` type that is not implicitly convertable to a `PsCredential` type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/netonly` runs the process as the current user and only network connections are made with the other credentials.

`Start-Process` will run the process (and all its network connections) with the other credentials. There's no way to achieve the `/NETONLY` functionality with `Start-Process`.

You'd have to p/invoke the Win32 API to achieve /NETONLY functionality. If you're up for the exercise this is the API you'll need to use `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` with:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/createprocesswithlogonw.html

More resources:

- [example code with `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/580e2d48-8dc6-4c37-ba98-caf5c1f2a5e8/)
- [CreateProcessWithTokenW function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682434%28VS.85%29.aspx)

To run a job as a different user:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {whoami} -Credential (get-credential) | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. As a follow up, Do you have any idea why get-credential might fail to validate when I enter an active directory user?

Comment: When the machine is not on the domain

Comment: Thankfully someone took the time to implement this and publish as a PowerShell Gallery module: https://github.com/gfody/PowershellModules/tree/master/RunAs